# Как сделать вывод нескольких переменных в строку на java?

Tags: java, python, строки

Допустим, на python это можно сделать так:

```
hello = "Привет"
world = "мир"
num = 1    
print("{} {}! #{}".format(hello, world, num))
```

Или, на python3, вот так:

```
hello = "Привет"
world = "мир"
num = 1    
print(f"{hello} {world}! #{num}")
```

Как аналогичное действие выполнить на java? Есть ли у стандартного System.out.println возможности, чтобы сделать что-то вроде:

```
String hello = "Привет";
String world = "мир";
int num = 1;
System.out.println("%hello, %world! #%num");
```

Или, возможно что-то подобное можно сделать с помощью других встроенных функций Java?

То что я нашёл в примерах выглядит как-то так:

```
System.out.printf("My name is: %s%n", "joe");
```

Но тут не ясно зачем эти %s и %n, а также как вывести несколько переменных в одной строке...

Comment: Можете использовать класс MessageFormat.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6389845/5741205

Comment: `System.out.println(String.format("%s + %s = %s", 3, 5, 8));`

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
String hello = "Привет";
String world = "мир";
int num = 1;
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s #%s", hello, world, num));
```

Спасибо MaxU и keekkenen. C MessageFormat вариант тоже рассмотрю.